# Does an open graph object have to correspond to a user visible page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have defined "book" to be an open graph object in my Facebook app. A book is a logical unit, and the user can view a book in a number of different ways in the app. However, there is no single URL in my app which corresponds to any single book.

I thought I would be able to have a URL which spits out open graph meta data to Facebook behind the scenes. For example http://www.example.com/opengrpah/object_book.php?id=3265 would return the title, author, and other info for a book, but not actually be user visible.

However it appears that Facebook uses the object URL for actions involving the object. If I create an action related to the book (e.g. add a book), then if somebody clicks on the link in the ticker they will go to the object_book.php URL, instead of an actual app page. Thus they will see the meta data but nothing useful.

Is this by design? Certainly an object shouldn't have to correspond to a single user-visible page. Can we not have object data drawn from one URL, but have that object displayed to the user within the context of an app?

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue here. In the end, how did you do it ?

Comment: ksol, I didn't find an answer. I am rearchitecting my app to have 1 page per object. I think it is the wrong design, but I have to do it in order to be able to user Timeline.

Comment: Looks like there is no way to achieve what we want for now, at least. I ended up using a specific controller for all my OG objects, then I do a redirection via JS. Seems to be the only way right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just redirecting from your Open Graph Object URL to the actual app page? Or how about designing your app pages to provide Open Graph metadata?

I think this could be a tricky solution.

Comment: Redirecting is technically feasible, but it is ugly, and I would prefer to avoid it. Providing Open Graph metadata in the app would require a complete redesign, as it is an AJAX app without fixed pages for each object.

I'm a bit surprised by the apparent implicit assumption in Open Graph that object pages map to user pages. It would make sense in 1995 when the Web was static, but now with dynamic content it doesn't.

Comment: According to your comment, I think your objects (may be books) in your app cannot be accessed by a specific 'URL'. Right? If so, that means your design is wrong.
I thinks the design decision of Facebook you mentioned in your comment is totally right. An 'object' should be able to be accessed by a specific URL, and you can provide metadata about that object in that URL handler.
AJAX doesn't mean that you don't need to provide URLs for objects.

Comment: Semun, AJAX absolutely means you don't have to provide user accessible URLs for objects. In my app, for example, lists of books are shown on a page, but individual books are shown in a floating div on the page which is populated by AJAX calls. As another example, a game could have many objects in it which should exist as open graph objects, but there are no user visible pages corresponding to them.

Comment: I think that AJAX is not absolutely related with the URL scheme. What will you show to the users who clicked the book link in the ticker, if Facebook allow you to send them to your actual app page? Just the lists of the books? Not the clicked book? IMHO, you should show the clicked book to the user with a specific URL of the book.

Answer (score 0):

In the app I'm working on we had a similar problem because it is an FB Canvas App, so if the og:url for our objects is something like http://apps.facebook.com/our_namespace/?my_first_obj=0 then FB sees the app itself instead of the object loaded in the app. That is where we ultimately want people to land, but we had to provide a direct URL to our app that provided the proper meta tags, much like your situation. I simply put this in the head of those pages:

```
<script>
    try {
        if (top.location.href === window.location.href) { 
            window.location.replace("http://apps.facebook.com/our_namespace/"+window.location.search);
        }
    } catch(e) {}
</script>
```

So if somebody is sent directly to that page, they are immediately redirected to our Canvas App, but Facebook's scraper can still get the correct meta data about the object.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I ended up with 2 layers for my objects. One is the "master" object, which is actually the object (book in your case, goal in mine). 
Then, I have another "user" object, which is actually an association between the master object and a user. This user object has the url like mysite/user/object and it's what I publish to the fb graph with the "add" action.